# what does the "@+android:id/title" mean?

Tags: android

In normal, we should use `@+id/` to define an id and use `@id` to reference an id. Today I found `@+android:id/title` in `apps/settings/res/layout/preferenc_progress.xml`.

How to understand it and how to use it?

Comment: Isn't it just an explicit namespace specifier?

Answer (score 4):

It is used for resources that are shipped with the SDK.

You can take a look at them by browsing to

> `[PATH TO ANDROID SDK]/platforms/android-[VERSION]/data/res`

By using the `android` in `android.R.whatever` you just specify the R file to look up. For more information you should read [Accessing Platform Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#PlatformResources).

Answer (score 1):

That belongs to the app preferences activity screen definition.
title and summary are standard Android fields of a TextView preference item.

Answer (score 0):

I've never met this way of giving id, but in theory this means adding new id `title` to `android` package. So you'll be able to use it in your code like `android.R.id.title`. But I'm not sure resource compiler will really create any id in `android` package. I think it can be used only with predefined ids. But I'll give you more precise answer later, when I'll be able to check it.

**EDIT**: I've checked it and found some differences. Firstly, if you define Android's id using `@+android:id/some_id`, which is already present in SDK, this id will not be defined in your R.java file. If it's not present in SDK, it will be defined in R.java, but with different kind of value. Secondly, if you'll try to convert id from its string representation to int value, `Resources.getIdentifier()` method will return 0 in case of `@+android:id` format.

Answer (score 0):

I think it does the same thing. It's just a more formal way of saying it by specifying where the namespace is.

Answer (score -1):

This means it will create an id in your resource file.