# Where are "android:id"s (IDs of system resources) stored?

Tags: android, android-resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what does the “@+android:id/title” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786829/what-does-the-androidid-title-mean)

For example: I have `android:id/summary` and `android:id/title`

But I don't realize where are they stored (I need some more ids).
I need them to use in layout like here:

```
<TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="40px"/>
```

I need IDs of system resources (not to create my own).

Comment: I don't understand your question, what are you wanting to do with these ids?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id

Comment: @Ralgha Sorry for not clear formulation of question, I meaned system resources

Comment: @Robert Sorry for not clear formulation of question, I meaned system resources

Comment: Did you read my comment ?

Comment: @Ty221 Yes, I've read it. Maybe my answer is still not clearly formulated but I need to know where "title" from "@android:id/title" is stored, because I want to het full list of these "title", "summary" and so on. It's not created by me, I refer to system resource and want to know where is it stored (or maybe "resource" is not correct naming for it?).

Comment: @Peter I've already flagged it for moderator's attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is `[PATH TO ANDROID SDK]/platforms/android-[VERSION]/data/res/*.xml`

Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6354998/1548085

Comment: this is duplicate of this question in that case

Comment: @Ty221 I've flagged it for moderator's attention because I can't delete it

Answer (score 0):

> Where are “android:id”s stored?

In your R.java file. (gen > package > R.java)

> I need some more ids

You can add ids, by adding a '+' sign:

```
android:id="@+id/myId"
```

Comment: Sorry for not clear formulation, I need ids of system resources. I've edited my question and added an example of use.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify new ID's by writing in the various layout files:

```
android:id="@+id/theIdName"
```

Or by creating a new XML file (put it in some "values" folder) using these lines:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item name="theIdName" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

After you create those in one of these ways, the R java file (which is auto-generated) will point it for you by accessing `R.id.****`

Comment: Sorry for not clear formulation, I need ids of system resources. I've edited my question and added an example of use.

Answer (score -1):

File with ids is in your project folder in : `gen - yourpackage -R.java`.

If you want to use id from this file write :`@id/idof` .

If you want to create new id : `@+id/newidname`.

The full list of system resources is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html)

Comment: Sorry for not clear formulation, I need ids of system resources. I've edited my question and added an example of use.

Comment: I added this info. Please edit your post

Comment: I've answered in comment to my question